# Error in displaying Date using <rich :calendar>

Tags: hibernate, jsf, richfaces

Bean

```
public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

Hibernate Mapping:

```
    <property name="startDate" type="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <column name="START_DATE" />
    </property>
```

```html
<tr><td><h:outputText value="Start date  "></h:outputText> 
    </td>
    <td><rich:calendar value="#{dateBean.startDate}"
       datePattern="d/M/yyyy"></rich:calendar>
    </td>
</tr>
```

While opening the webpage, the date is not getting displayed and gives error  [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siSq0.png) as 
**"2017-05-14 21:31:09,113 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-2) textarea"**

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the calendar? The error message says "textarea" and there is no textarea in calendar. Do you know where the error is coming from?

Comment: Yes. There is no textarea.The date gets stored in database. While retrieving in dataTable ,there is no problem.But the date is not getting displayed in rich:calender and gives error

Comment: Maybe your 'datePattern' should be `datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: @Yumiko yes, but the error doesn't look like it's coming from calendar. Something else on your page can be broken causing a problem with the calendar (or maybe it's completely unrelated), can you find out what is throwing the error? Where do you see the error? On the page, in the console, server log?

Comment: From Server log i found this error. This error gets generated whenever i open the page with startDate . And even i tried changing the datePattern. But still same error happens

Comment: And what happens if you remove the calendar?

Comment: If i remove the calender then there is no error

Comment: Now there is no textarea error .But Date is not getting displayed in richcalender